# Unhandled Promise rejection error angular 2 using angular cli

Tags: angular, promise, command-line-interface, unhandled

Hi I am working on the tutorial provided at this link -

http://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial

With the changes done for http part of the tutorial I get the following error :

Unhandled Promise rejection: "patchProperty/desc.set/wrapFn@http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:769:27
 Zonehttp://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:356:24
 Zonehttp://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:29
 ZoneTask/this.invoke@http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:423:29

Error loading http://localhost:4200/main" ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: patchProperty/desc.set/wrapFn@http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:769:27
 Zonehttp://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:356:24
 Zonehttp://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:29
 ZoneTask/this.invoke@http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:423:29

Error loading http://localhost:4200/main

**The question is how to fix the above error**

Comment: If you're using angular 2 and not angularjs, please swap the angularjs tag for angular 2.

Comment: Also, state what your question is. You haven't asked a question. You've just made a statement. It would also help to give a bit more background on how to recreate the error. If the error cannot be recreated, you might  find it tough to get an answer.

Comment: I'm getting the same errror, can anyone have a solution on this?